# Microdata for sidebars with list of articles

Tags: schema.org, microdata

This is The structure of my first page site

```
<body>
<div class="header"></div>

<div class="left_col">List of last articles/news</div>
<div class="center_cod">List of feature articles/news</div>
<div class="right_col">other thing like ads,and other item list</div>


<div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

What do you suggested me to use Microdata in each of  element?

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
<div class="header" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader"></div>

<div class="left_col" itemscope itemtype="?">List of last articles/news</div>
<div class="center_cod" itemscope itemtype="?">List of feature articles/news</div>
<div class="right_col" itemscope itemtype="?">other thing like ads,and other item list</div>


<div class="footer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPFooter"></div>
</body>
```

Yes I know there is 'itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPSideBar"' for sidebar...But I wana more cutomize it... for example can I use 'blog' or something like this?

Comment: Is `.center_cod` the main content for that page? And why would you want to use blog for your sidebar?

Comment: In The .left_cod I hold only list of 50 last article (just hyperlink title)....and in The center_cod I hold list of 10 last important article/news (feature news/hot news with hyperlink title,image and a short descibtion)